# Drupal - Issue with passing a PHP variable to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, drupal, drupal-7

I built a custom google map php file to implement into the front page of my drupal site that uses both javascript and php, and it is being called via `drupal_add_js` in the template.php file. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to properly run the PHP within the javascript, and then set the results to the JavaScript variable `markers`. I'm attempting to push each result to an array and echo the array via `json_encode($item);` however, in my console, i'm getting an error that is `Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined`.

Here is my entire map.php:

```
var map = null;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var markers = [Drupal.settings.markers];

window.onload = function () {

var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat(markers[0].lat),
        parseFloat(markers[0].lng)),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();
var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({map: map, strokeColor: '#F3443C'});

var lat_lng = new Array();
           for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
           var data = markers[i]
           var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
           lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: myLatlng,
               map: map,
               title: data.title
           });
           (function (marker, data) {
               google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                   infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                   infoWindow.open(map, marker);
               });
           })(marker, data);
       }
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    if ((i + 1) < markers.length) {
        var src = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].lat), 
                                         parseFloat(markers[i].lng));
        var des = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i+1].lat), 
                                         parseFloat(markers[i+1].lng));
        service.route({
            origin: src,
            destination: des,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                for (var i = 0, len = result.routes[0].overview_path.length; i < len; i++) {
                    path.push(result.routes[0].overview_path[i]);
                }
                poly.setPath(path);
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

and here is my page--front.tpl.php with my attempt in creating the array that will be accessible to my js file:

```
<?php

  if (isset($_GET['routeselected'])) 
  {
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM STOP INNER JOIN RouteStop ON Stop.Stop_ID = RouteStop.Stop_ID WHERE RouteStop.Route_ID = " . (int)$_GET['routeselected'] . " AND RouteStop.Company_ID = " . (int)$_GET['companyselected']);
  $markers = array();
  while (($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))){
      $markers[$row['title']] = array($row['Stop_ID']);
      $markers[$row['lat']] = array($row['Latitude']);
      $markers[$row['lng']] = array($row['Longitude']);
      $markers[$row['description']] = array($row['StopName']);
      }
    drupal_json_encode($markers);
    drupal_add_js(array('markers' => drupal_json_encode($markers)), 'setting');
  }
  ?>
```

Does anyone possibly know the solution to my issue? Thank you for all and any help!

Comment: thanks, so basically just add `json_encode()` like so? `<?php echo " {\"title\": '".json_encode($row['Stop_ID']).";} ?>`

Comment: No, you don't output anything until the end of your script / database operation. You add everything to an array and at the end `json_encode` that array.

Answer (score 2):

Writing inline PHP code inside javascript file is really a bad idea.

The solution is:

- Move that php code to a module
- Generate $markers as a PHP associative array/object
- Convert it to JSON using `drupal_json_encode($markers)`
- Add it to `Drupal.settings.markers` using 
  `drupal_add_js(array('markers' => drupal_json_encode($markers)), 'setting');`
- And in your js use `var markers = Drupal.settings.markers`

For more details, have a look at this article: https://drupal.org/node/756722#settings-javascript

Comment: Thank you for your response! Will it work if I just generate `$markers` in my `page--front.tpl.php`? I've attempted to rework my code, i will alter my question with the rework. It still does not work, I think I may be populating the array incorrectly. Do you mind taking a look at my new code?